# Java extracting substring from sentences

Tags: java

There are combination of words like is, is not, does not contain. We have to match these words in a sentence and have to split it.

**Intput** : `if name is tom and age is not 45 or name does not contain tom then let me know.`

**Expected output:**

```
If name is 
tom and age is not 
45 or name does not contain 
tom then let me know
```

I tried below code to split and extract but the occurrence of "is" is in "is not" as well which my code is not able to find out:

```
public static void loadOperators(){
        operators.add("is");
        operators.add("is not");
        operators.add("does not contain");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadOperators();
    for(String s : operators){
        System.out.println(str.split(s).length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input and your output are identical.

Comment: Please show exact input and expected output.  I am skeptical that splitting a sentence is as trivial as you think, certainly not in English.

Comment: So, you want to add a line break after each searched combination of words? Is that what you want? You can just use String.replace() to do that.

Comment: Simply spoken: your question is unclear. Before you even **start** thinking about code, you need a complete **in depth** understanding of your **requirements**. A simple example is not at all sufficient to outline *requirements*. Seriously: until you are able to exactly communicate **what** you want to achieve ... putting down code is futile.

Answer (score 0):

Since there could be multiple occurence of a word `split` wouldn't solve your use case, as in `is` and `is not` being different operators for you. You would ideally :

```
Iterate :
1. Find the index of the 'operator'.
2. Search for the next space _ or word.
3. Then update your string as substring from its index to length-1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about what you try to achieve, but let's give it a shot.

For your case, a simple "workaround" might work just fine:
Sort the operators by their length, descending. This way the "largest match" will get found first. You can define "largest" as either literally the longest string, or preferably the number of words (number of spaces contained), so `is a` has precedence over `contains`

You'll need to make sure that no matches overlap though, which can be done by comparing all matches' start and end indices and discarding overlaps by some criteria, like first match wins

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you seem to be wanting to do (or what I guessed you are wanting to do):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
    operators.add("is");
    operators.add("is not");
    operators.add("does not contain");

    String input = "if name is tom and age is not 45 or name does not contain tom then let me know.";
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    int lastFoundOperatorsEndIndex = 0; // First start at the beginning of input

    for (String operator : operators){
        int indexOfOperator = input.indexOf(operator); // Find current operator's position

        if (indexOfOperator > -1) { // If operator was found
            int thisOperatorsEndIndex = indexOfOperator + operator.length(); // Get length of operator and add it to the index to include operator
            output.add(input.substring(lastFoundOperatorsEndIndex, thisOperatorsEndIndex).trim()); // Add operator to output (and remove trailing space)
            lastFoundOperatorsEndIndex = thisOperatorsEndIndex; // Update startindex for next operator
        }
    }
    output.add(input.substring(lastFoundOperatorsEndIndex, input.length()).trim()); // Add rest of input as last entry to output

    for (String part : output) { // Output to console
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```

But it is highly dependant on the order of the sentence and the operators. If we're talking about user-input, the task will be **much** more complicated.

A better method using regular expressions (regExp) would be:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    // Define inputs
    String input1 = "if name is tom and age is not 45 or name does not contain tom then let me know.";
    String input2 = "the name is tom and he is 22 years old but the name does not contain jack, but merry is 24 year old.";

    // Output split strings
    for (String part : split(input1)) {
        System.out.println(part.trim());
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (String part : split(input2)) {
        System.out.println(part.trim());
    }
}

private static String[] split(String input) {
    // Define list of operators - 'is not' has to precede 'is'!!
    String[] operators = { "\\sis not\\s", "\\sis\\s", "\\sdoes not contain\\s", "\\sdoes contain\\s" };

    // Concatenate operators to regExp-String for search
    StringBuilder searchString = new StringBuilder();

    for (String operator : operators) {
        if (searchString.length() > 0) {
            searchString.append("|");
        }
        searchString.append(operator);
    }

    // Replace all operators by operator+\n and split resulting string at \n-character
    return input.replaceAll("(" + searchString.toString() + ")", "$1\n").split("\n");
}
```

Notice the order of the operators! 'is' has to come **after** 'is not' or 'is not' will always be split.

You can prevent this by using a *negative lookahead* for the operator 'is'.
So `"\\sis\\s"` would become `"\\sis(?! not)\\s"` (reading like: "is", not followed by a " not").

A minimalist Version (with JDK 1.6+) could look like this:

```
private static String[] split(String input) {
    String[] operators = { "\\sis(?! not)\\s", "\\sis not\\s", "\\sdoes not contain\\s", "\\sdoes contain\\s" };
    return input.replaceAll("(" + String.join("|", operators) + ")", "$1\n").split("\n");
}
```

Comment: But for repetition of 'is' it is not working: If name is 'tom' and lastname is 'jerry' or age is not '16' or name does not  contain 'tom'. As per your logic output is (in second line "is" is not processed):                                                                                                  If name is
'tom' and lastname is 'jerry' or age is not
'16' or name does not  contain 'tom'

Comment: That's what I meant by 'highly dependant'. If you want to analyse natural sentences, you'll need a more complex approach. RegExp, looking for the keywords for example.

Comment: I added an example using regExp. It is still dependant on the order of the operators 'is' and 'is not' (or any other operator, containing another operator).

Comment: I added another line, explaining how to use regExp's negative lookahead to make order of the operators independent.

Comment: If operator will be part of word say for example I replace one of the "or" with "oris" then it will split for "oris" also even though it is not operator.

Comment: These are all conditions which can be resolved by extending the regExp (what I did for words, containing an operator).
I'd suggest you consider looking at the [documentation on Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you can extend the conditions as you like.
You will soon encounter several scenarios where you will need more and more conditions. The more complex the sentences get, the more complex and unmaintainable the expressions will become.